# At which academic institute(s) has Javier Milei held a professorship?

Tags: president, argentina

It is fairly common for articles on Argentinian President-elect, Javier Milei, to mention that he is a professor. For example, [Time](https://time.com/6326834/javier-milei-argentina-presidential-race-candidate-bio/) and [Fortune](https://fortune.com/2023/10/08/who-is-javier-mileil-argentina-presidential-election-frontrunner-anarcho-capitalist-dollarize/) both do so, in articles published in October 2023.

His [biography](https://www.weforum.org/people/javier-gerardo-milei/) on the website of the World Economic Forum also refers to him as,

> University Professor of Macroeconomics, Economics of Growth, Microeconomics and Mathematics for Economists.

However, I am unable to discover *where* he is a professor. The WEF biography only clearly identifies roles in industry, think tanks and as a government advisor. The papers he has published, that I have seen, either don't state his affiliation, or list it as Fundación Acordar, which is a think tank.

Searching for an answer to this has been hampered by the huge amount of noise caused by Milei's political prominence, but perhaps someone with better detective skills than me get to the bottom of it.

Comment: TBH I've only seen him described as an economist recently.

Comment: Is there a reason the phrasing of the title is so skeptical? What's wrong with "Where is Milei a professor?"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I chose this phrasing to cover both past and present instances of Milei holding a professorship. It wasn't my intention for the title to have a particularly skeptical tone, and I don't think it does.

Comment: I just meant more professorships aren't usually things that are "granted." It makes it sound like you think any professorship he has held have been corrupt sinecures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems Milei has held multiple professorships. As far back as 2010, in a paper entitled *El elixir de la teoría monetaria Argentina: Apuesta por el error tipo ll o una pasión desenfrenada por la inflación*, he is described as "Professor of the Chair of Monetary Economics at the UBA [University of Buenos Aires] and the UADE [Argentine University of Enterprise]".

In 2020, (it appears in response to an accusation that he had inflated his professorship credentials) Milei [stated](https://twitter.com/JMilei/status/1254740831145164800) that he was "a Professor of Monetary Theory 1 and 2 at the UB [University of Belgrano]". This is confirmed by various press releases on the UB website. Milei also [claimed](https://twitter.com/JMilei/status/693261850184671232) in 2016 to have held professorships at "UBA, USAL, UB, UNC among others".

In addition, according to Juan Luis González's biography of Milei, in December 2022 the Escuela Superior de Economía y Administración de Empresas (ESEADE) also presented him with an honorary doctorate and the title of visiting professor.

There is a [video](https://www.eseade.edu.ar/que-paso-en-eseade/entrega-del-doctorado-honoris-causa-a-javier-milei/) of the presentation on ESEADE's website in Spanish which confirms this.

> During 2022 many memorable things happened at ESEADE UNIVERSIDAD that
> will undoubtedly impact 2023. The awarding of the Honoris Causa
> Doctorate to Dr Javier Milei and the incorporation of him as a
> professor in the Diploma in Austrian Economics, in Microfinance and in
> the Master's Degree in Economics and Political Sciences is one of
> them.

Comment: Good answer. It's interesting that, in many cases, he is described as being a professor of a particular course, rather than a field. Perhaps this is quite normal in Argentina, I don't know.